# UITableView should go beyond its frame when scrolled

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Am trying out an example app using UITableView.

The upper (nearly) half of the screen is filled by a UIView which has some components like button, text field, and an image view. The lower half (In IB, its width=320 and height=234 pixels) is filled by a UITableView instance.

[image]

Am using custom UITableViewCell objects to be displayed within this UITableView.

This is the **size definition** of the UITableView instance in IB:

[image]

And this is the size definition for the UITableViewCell:

[image]

I have defined two types of custom UITableView cells that can be placed in the UITableView (and the decision of which type is decided dynamically based on whether the cell has a picture to be displayed, or not). Cells with picture are bigger and have a different layout than those without. The custom UITableViewCell which has a picture has these size parameters in IB (the height '301' is more than that for the generic UITableViewCell instance '234' specified in the main Storyboard in the screenshot above of the entire screen):

[image]

Now, when I run the app and scroll the table view, the table view needs to scroll along the entire screen (i.e. the first half of the screen that has a UIView with she components should also scroll away), just like in the Path app like this:

This is the initial screen in the Path App: (the top half is some fixed UIView and those below in the 2nd half of the screen is the timeline, which is a UITableView)

[image]

When you start scrolling the timeline, the upper half also scrolls away:

[image]

How can I do this (i.e the top half also scrolls away)?
I tried adding a UIScrollView to the entire screen and put it behind all the other components in the screen, but this didn't help.
Can someone please suggest ? or any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the UITableView take up the entire screen, and add your view that now takes the top half as the headerView of the table view (you can just drag it ontop of it in the interface builder and it should snap right in).